# add parameter to Laravel Accessor

Tags: laravel

I have an accessor that is defined like that:

```
public function getNameAttribute($name)
{
    return trans($name);
}
```

Now, I would like to add parameters to my translation, so I would like to have something like that:

```
public function getNameAttribute($name)
{
    return trans($name, ['age' => $age]);
}
```

Is it possible? How should I define accessor, and how should I call send the param?

EDIT 1: Here are my model attributes:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'gender',
    'isTeam',
    'ageCategory',
    'ageMin',
    'ageMax',
    'gradeCategory',
    'gradeMin',
    'gradeMax',
];
```

And here is how I get $age variable inside my model:

```
public function getAgeString()
{
    $ageCategoryText = '';
    $ageCategories = [
        0 => trans('core.no_age'),
        1 => trans('core.children'),
        2 => trans('core.students'),
        3 => trans('core.adults'),
        4 => trans('core.masters'),
        5 => trans('core.custom')
    ];

    if ($this->ageCategory != 0) {
        if ($this->ageCategory == 5) {
            $ageCategoryText = ' - ' . trans('core.age') . ' : ';
            if ($this->ageMin != 0 && $this->ageMax != 0) {
                if ($this->ageMin == $this->ageMax) {
                    $ageCategoryText .= $this->ageMax . ' ' . trans('core.years');
                } else {
                    $ageCategoryText .= $this->ageMin . ' - ' . $this->ageMax . ' ' . trans('core.years');
                }

            } else if ($this->ageMin == 0 && $this->ageMax != 0) {
                $ageCategoryText .= ' < ' . $this->ageMax . ' ' . trans('core.years');
            } else if ($this->ageMin != 0 && $this->ageMax == 0) {
                $ageCategoryText .= ' > ' . $this->ageMin . ' ' . trans('core.years');
            } else {
                $ageCategoryText = '';
            }
        } else {
            $ageCategoryText = $ageCategories[$this->ageCategory];
        }
    }
    return $ageCategoryText;
}
```

Comment: $age is a attribute of your model?

Comment: @JoseRojas it can't be otherwise it would be $this->age;

Comment: mmm nop, it is a string built with 2 model attributes: $this->ageMin, $this->ageMax, with a function within model

Comment: can you post that function? @JuliatzindelToro

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options,

First:

If you want to get as attribute name a message translated, you can try this:

```
public function getNameAttribute($name)
{
   return trans($name, ['age' => $this->getAgeString()]);
}
```

Second:

If you want a translate as additional field you can use `Mutator` adding an append to your model:

```
protected $appends = array('nameWithAge');
```

and define the method to get the name

```
public function getNameWithAgeAttribute()
{
    return trans($this->attributes['name'], ['age' => $this->getAgeString()]);
}
```

This will do to nameWithAge an attribute more of the model and you can access it as such.

Comment: If you choose the mutator option No, this is based on other attribute that you want to transform, in this case getAgeString, are 2 solutions sorry If I don't make me understand

Comment: With mutator option you get the value you want as $model->nameWithAge @JuliatzindelToro